# Does there exist a vector field s.t. all orbits are dense on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

Is there a complete vector field such that the all orbits are dense on a contractible manifold?
For example, $\mathbb{R}^2$,the interior of a $n$-unit ball.

Comment: I think this is a great question. More generally *which* manifolds admit such vector fields. The answer is probably given by some theorem in the theory of foliations.  Hopefully someone like Ryan Budney sees this and can answer it. In the meantime I hope you don't mind if I add a few tags.

Comment: If instead of orbits you restrict only to forward semi-orbits then such flows do not exist on any noncompact manifold.

Comment: @user134146 in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ it is impossible. Assume that $S$ is a a part of a line which is tranverse to the vec. field.$S$ is called  a local section. Then every solution which intersects $S$, the points of its intersection  with $S$ is  arranged in a monotone manner. (See the method of proof of the Poincare Bendixon theorem). This implies that there is no a dense solution for a plannar vec. field(See Hirsch, Smale: Linear algebra, diff. equation, dynamical system"

Comment: @MoisheKohan can you give me a hint to proof that on a non-compact manifold there is no $C^1$ vector field with foward semi-orbits dense?.